# javascript : casting int to char trouble

Tags: javascript, casting

I have a small script that read delta X and Y of a joystick and next cast they into character:

```
var a =deltaX.toString();
var b =deltaY.toString();
outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
    + a
    + b;    
var comando = a + b ;
```

the trouble is I need number lower than 10 and -10 , to be 2 characters , so for example 5 , to be 05 . what's should be a good way to add the zero in the numbers lower than 10 and -10 ?

Comment: A simple series of `if` conditions should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a ternary operator (inline if) by looking at the length-property:

```
outputEl.innerHTML  = '<b>Result:</b> '
            + a.length > 1 ? a : '0' + a
            + b.length > 1 ? b : '0' + b;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a;

if (deltaX < 10) {
  // one digit
  a = '0' + deltaX;
} else {
  a = deltaX.toString();
}
```

Note that this doesn't handle the negative portion, but I am showing a proof of concept. Since your numbers are so small, you can pad with a simple `if` statement, rather than an air-tight method to pad zeros.

Comment: Code golf! `var a = deltaX < 10 ? '0' + deltaX : deltaX.toString();`

Comment: the code work good for positive number. with negative numbers the "-" is show after the first "0" , so I think I have to make the number positive and then add the "-" before the "0" right?